# [Hibernate][Oracle11.2]org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException issue

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have some issue as I started recently to write some code in hibernate.Here are my main class and my hibernate config file:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Maven + Hibernate + Oracle");
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();      

        session.beginTransaction();
        DBUser user = new DBUser();

        user.setUserId(100);
        user.setUsername("superman");
        user.setCreatedBy("system");
        user.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        session.persist(user);
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:franklin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">franklin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
       <property name="hibernate.default_schema">franklin</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.formatsql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.showsql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="com/mkyong/user/DBUser.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

While running it, it results in the following lines:

```
-Hibernate: insert into mkyong.DBUSER (USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, USER_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
-Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
-at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
-at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
-at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
-at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
-at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
-at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
-at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
-at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
-at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
-at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
-at com.ftamen.App.main(App.java:24)
+Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00942: tabella o vista inesistente

-at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10500)
-at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
-at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
*   at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
*   ... 8 more
```

Can some one help me in solving this issue please?